# Libsvm - predicted results are NULL

Tags: python, csv, libsvm

I am using LibSVM (3.18). But every time when I'm predicting the result it is giving zero.

I am following these instructions:

- I have csv file (+20K lines), Most of data in column (target) is zeros, the other values are between 0-10.
- I convert csv file to libsvm data by selecting this column as label.
- When I Scale Data, I use these parameters

  $ svm-scale -l 0 -u 1 data.cv>scaled.data
- As I have a huge file, I use Subset.py.
- When I finish all the steps and apply predict. I got good result of accuracy.
  $svm-predict scaled_data.csv model.train data.predicted

Accuracy = 94.28%

but the file I get (data.predicted) contains only zeros.

Is it tricky to predict this kind of data ? Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Can you please post the code you have used?  And possibly the first few lines of input?

Comment: Yes, this is a tricky problem. The usual way to solve it is to oversample the minority class so that it has as many samples as the majority one. I never used raw LibSVM myself, but it looks like the `-wi` option can take care of this.

Comment: But when I use weight flag; How accurate is this 'cause we are re-influencing the dataset with positive results that doesn't exist? Is there any other approach to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first learn about your data. are the classes separable or near inseparable? or completely unknown? you could use a NN classifier to find out whether your classes are clustered or not. second, avoid subset.py as you may miss most of your non-zero samples and use the whole set. if you still fail manually do a subset where the number of "zero" class samples is in the range of the other non-zero classes to verify your process (are you using the shipped tools or own code?). if this is working out you could start with the whole set again and use the weight option. if weight is doing the job you have to evaluate your [Confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) carefully whether your classifier is useful at all with respect to your requirements.